# Increased memory usage after updating to wordpress 4.3

Tags: updates

I recently updated to wordpress 4.3 and I noticed an increased memory usage on my server. Sometimes the memory usage is as double as the previous one.

Does anyone has the same experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, we experienced the same problem. It's related to cron events. Reversed arguments for scheduled task to split terms can cause the database to explode.

There is a major bug that has been resolved, see [this ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/33423).

@Otto posted a solution to this bug in the WordPress support forums [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/high-cpu-load-after-update-to-v43?replies=79#post-7330770). This solution worked for us.

Simply put, open wp-includes/taxonomy.php and replace:

```
wp_schedule_single_event( 'wp_batch_split_terms', time() + MINUTE_IN_SECONDS );
```

With:

```
wp_schedule_single_event( time() + MINUTE_IN_SECONDS, 'wp_batch_split_terms' );
```

On top of this, you need to create a `must use` plugin with the following code:

```
<?php
function clear_bad_cron_entries() {
    // Fix incorrect cron entries for term splitting
    $cron_array = _get_cron_array();
    if ( isset( $cron_array['wp_batch_split_terms'] ) ) {
        unset( $cron_array['wp_batch_split_terms'] );
            _set_cron_array( $cron_array );
    }
}
clear_bad_cron_entries();
```

Run that only once.

I would highly recommend that you read through [Otto's detailed guide](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/high-cpu-load-after-update-to-v43?replies=79#post-7330770) on this if you don't know what you are doing.

There is also a hotfix plugin available [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp33423-hotfix/).

The answer to why WordPress hasn't carried out a 4.3.1. push with more than two weeks of discovering this bug is completely beyond me.